# How to combine longtable and column-specifiers like >{$}r<{$}?

Tags: longtable, columns

How do I combine the functionality of the environment "longtable" (a table can span multiple pages, with automatic copies of the caption and header row after each page-break) and column-specifiers such as ">{$}r<{$}"? I find the latter very useful in tables which contain both columns with mathematical content and columns with text content.

MnWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[l]{>{$}r<{$}l}
x&note\\
\endhead
\sqrt{\pi-1}&lorem ipsum
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

TeXworks gives error messages as follows:

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \begin{longtable}[l]{>{$}r<{$}l}

?
```

TeXworks is usually good at pinpointing to the individual character where it thinks the error is, but, rather annoyingly, it hasn't in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You're just missing the `array` package, which provides the `>{...}` and `<{...}` syntax. If you load it as well everything works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[l]{>{$}r<{$}l}
x&note\\
\endhead
\sqrt{\pi-1}&lorem ipsum
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```